# Openpyxl, max_highest_column gives an error. Worksheet object has no attribute 'max_highest_column'?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am learning python using the "automate the boring stuff with python".

```
import openpyxl, smtplib, sys

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Book1.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

lastCol = sheet.max_column()
latestMonth = sheet.cell(row=1, column=lastCol).value

unpaidMember = {}
for r in range(2, sheet.get_highest_row() + 1):
    payment = sheet.cell(row=r, column=lastCol).value
    if payment != 'Y':
        name = sheet.cell(row=r, column=1).value
        email = sheet.cell(row=r, column=2).value
        unpaidMembers[name] = email


smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp-mail.outlook.com', 587)
smtpObj.ehlo()
smtpObj.starttls()
smtpObj.login('xxx@outlook.com ', 'xxxxx')

for name, email in unpaidMembers.items():
    body = "Subject: Hi \n----- \n\n -----."
    print('Sending email to %s...' % email)
    sendmailStatus = smtp0bj.sendmail('xxx@outlook.com', email, body)

    if sendmailStatus != {}:
        print('There was a problem sending email to %s: %s' % (email, sendmailStatus))

smtp0bj.quit()
```

The above gives me the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "C:\Python34\Email Marketing.py", line 6, in 
>      lastCol = sheet.max_highest_column()
>   AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'max_highest_column'

I looked around a bit and changed sheet.max_highest_column to sheet.max_column and then I get the following:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "C:\Python34\Email Marketing.py", line 6, in 
>      lastCol = sheet.max_column()
>   TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

I am unable to understand what the problem might be. Book1 is saved in the current directory, double checked.

### Edit:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lugs and Thimbles Email Marketing.py", line 19, in     <module>
    smtp0bj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp-mail.outlook.com', 587)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\smtplib.py", line 242, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\smtplib.py", line 321, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\smtplib.py", line 292, in _get_socket
    self.source_address)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 512, in create_connection
   raise err
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 503, in create_connection  
    sock.connect(sa)
 TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected      party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection     failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Then I tried all the commands in Idle:

```
import smtplib, sys
smtp0bj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp-mail.outlook.com', 587)
smtp0bj.ehlo()
(250, b'BLU436-SMTP113.smtp.hotmail.com Hello [120.59.245.82]\nTURN\nSIZE       41943040\nETRN\nPIPELINING\nDSN\nENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\n8bitmime\nBINARYMIME\nCHUN    KING\nVRFY\nTLS\nSTARTTLS\nOK')
smtp0bj.starttls()
(220, b'2.0.0 SMTP server ready')
smtp0bj.login('xxxx@xxxx.com ', 'xxxxx')
(235, b'2.7.0 Authentication succeeded')
```

I tried all the code before `for name, email in unpaidMembers.items()` and got the correct response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to call an int (as the error says).
You have to change: `lastCol = sheet.max_column()` with `lastCol = sheet.max_column`. You are expecting the max_column value and not the object iteself.

You are also mixing `UnpaidMember` and  `UnpaidMembers`

Comment: Thanks, I just changed the code as per your and @DeepSpace's comments. Getting a brand new error. Which I am trying to research. Might have to post it up. Thanks guys.

The error just incase its possible to sort quickly:

>Sending email to xxxx@gmail.com...
>Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "C:\Python34\Lugs and Thimbles Email Marketing.py", line 26, in ><module>
>    sendmailStatus = smtp0bj.sendmail('sidgoyal@outlook.com', email, >body)
>NameError: name 'smtp0bj' is not defined

Comment: @Sid Seems like you interchanged `O` (upper case `O`) and `0` (zero) in the variable name.

Comment: Yes, @DeepSpace

Comment: @DeepSpace I checked it again, changed it a bit. But Now:

_Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lugs and Thimbles Email Marketing.py", line 26, in <module>
    sendmailStatus = smtp0bj.sendmail('xxx@xxxx.com', email, body)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\smtplib.py", line 764, in sendmail
    msg = _fix_eols(msg).encode('ascii')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2013' in position 801: ordinal not in range(128)_

Comment: if you check the value of some column (extracted via OpenPyXl) you can see that they are unicode strings. Try with `email = email.encode('ascii', 'replace')` right after `email = sheet.cell(row=r, column=2).value`

Comment: @andrepogg I added the line. Now getting errors as updated in the question above, It wont fit here.

Comment: I don't know what you are you think `ehlo` do... But you can try to set `helo` and/or `ehlo_or_helo_if_needed()`. But I suggest you to take a look to the smtplib documentation [here] (https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html)

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the error `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable` because `max_column` is an `int`, not a function/method. Therefore you should be doing `lastCol = sheet.max_column` (no `()`).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. The thing is I want it to check for the last column. It was my understanding that: `lastCol = sheet.max_highest_column()` would pull the last column on the sheet.

Comment: @Sid I don't know which version of openpyxl you are using, but the latest one (2.4) doesn't have any attribute called `max_highest_column` in its `Worksheet` class: http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.4/_modules/openpyxl/worksheet/worksheet.html

Comment: FWIW try avoid calling `ws.max_row` and `ws.max_column` as it's usually not necessary and can be expensive if done a lot.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Andrepogg and your comments have made the code work. Going through the resource provided now. :)